# Need help getting 190Vpp to signal readable by AD/DA

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, high-voltage, high-frequency

I created a system that records the rate of oil being pumped through a turbine using a [Honeywell 3030AN VRS Magnetic Speed Sensor](https://sensing.honeywell.com/3030AN-passive-speed-sensors). The 3030AN output voltage is 190 Vpp and I have an [8AI-SPI](https://widgetlords.com/collections/pi-spi-series) AD/DA connected to a Raspberry Pi 3 which reads the change in voltage.

I'm looking for a Frequency-to-Voltage converter that will convert the 190 Vpp (15 kHz operating frequency) to a voltage readable by the 8AI-SPI.

I tried contacting Honeywell to see what they recommend for their VRS sensors, but have yet to get a reply. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to specify the minimum voltage you need to detect when the turbine is running slowly.

Comment: Um.. why are you trying to convert the frequency into a voltage?

Comment: For d'analog inputs, @Trevor. Would you recommend counting at 15 kHz on the Pi?

Comment: 15 kHz is the maximum frequency of your sensor. What frequency will you actually be operating it at?

Comment: @Transistor that may be a bit high for a Pi, but assuming he does not need immediate control, a suitable prescaler should be accurate enough for this kind of thing.

Comment: I'm trying to work out why you think you need a F/V conversion when the VRS produces pulses that you need to count. The p-p analog value has no relevance. You do need to figure out what the highest pulse rate is that you will get from your flow sensor(vane). Short answer, it appear you only need to pulse count, so don't need an A/D at all.   https://sensing.honeywell.com/vrs-app-note-005934-2-en-final-26jun12.pdf

Comment: I was only trying find a F/V converter as that is what I was under the assumption I needed. The system that was used previously had the output from the 3030AN going directly into [this](https://imgur.com/a/hrSe2), however there is no documentation as to what exactly this is. I'd rather know exactly what I'm using so that I can replace it in the future as well as make sure that I'm getting an accurate reading. I apologize for my lack of understanding of the concepts, but that is why I came here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can do this digitally, instead of converting to a voltage, simply detect zero-ish crossings and use that to create a square wave. The documentation on the sensor is very lacking in terms of how you hook it up, but if I am understanding it properly, this simple crossover circuit would create a 5V "square wave" suitable for clocking some counter or timer in your micro.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fECUhj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The data sheet is also unclear if the signal is biased at ground or not, though I can't see how it would not be. However, if it is not, a suitably high voltage series capacitor before R1 would be required.

I have a feeling 190V may be a bit excessive though. Depending on what your minimum RPM is on whatever you are measuring, you may be able to drop R1 to somewhere closer to 10K, which would make the max voltage less, and make this thing a tad less scary.

Answer (score 3):

Given it appears that you are interested in frequency, you could probably do the signal conditioning fairly simply.

One option is a small transformer connected to the output of the sensor which provides a 100:1 turn ratio or something similar - that would give you a 1.9Vpp signal nominally that is isolated from the high voltage.

Another option would be capacitive coupling followed by a 100:1 potential divider of two resistors. Again the capacitive coupling (both + and - sides) gives you isolation as long as you use sufficiently high voltage rated caps, and the potential divider brings the signal down to something useful in terms of voltage level.

In both cases you could use a Schmitt trigger or as a zero-crossing detector circuit as @Trever points out after the division to perform a final conditioning step - take whatever weird waveform you get out of the circuit and convert it to a digital logic signal which is then much easier to process.

Once you have a digital signal with sensible voltage level you can feed that into a frequency measuring circuit. I wouldn't do frequency to voltage as you are taking a nice digital signal, converting it into an analogue signal (introducing error in the process), only to then convert it back to digital again. Instead I would use something like a simple MCU with a timer to count the period between transitions. If you get an MCU with a hardware SPI or I2C slave you can connect it quite easily with the Pi and have it report back the frequency.

Comment: One issue (especially for the schmitt trigger idea) is that the amplitude will decrease along with the frequency as the monitored speed drops. Depending on the range of speeds OP needs to monitor this could be no issue or all or make things a lot trickier.

Comment: @ThePhoton that's true, with something like this you really ought to be detecting zero crossings anyway.

Comment: @Trevor, can you tell me the best way to get the signal to a readable level for my situation? I could email you all the details and maybe you could help me come up with what I'm looking for?

Comment: @DustinHuntoon I gave two options for how to get the signal to a readable level.